How to stop websites in Firefox from nagging about adding them as an application for mailto links?
I'm using Outlook online for some corporate inboxes that I have. I access it using Firefox on Windows (currently version 126.0).
All too often, the web application at https://outlook.office.com/ nags me with a prompt to:

Add "outlook.office.com" as an application for mailto links?

As shown in this screenshot:

I keep refusing by clicking the "X" button on the right to make the prompt go away, only for it to return a while later or after I close and re-open the browser.
Is there a way to block this particular website, or all web sites, from prompting me to add them for mailto links permanently?

I was able to find an answer online so answering my own question.
To stop all websites from attempting to register to handle "mailto" links, follow these instructions in Firefox:

Open a new tab and browse to the address about:config.
Read the warning displayed in the page and then click on the button that says "Accept the Risk and Continue".
In the search box that is shown, search for the key network.protocol-handler.external.mailto.
When the key is shown, its default value is set to true. Toggle it to false.
Close the browser tab.


